# Implementing Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I wish to implement a timer which runs for 60 seconds. So basically, my app receives heart rate values from a device. I wish to capture 60 seconds of these values and then pass it on to a function for further calculation. I have seen the various solutions posted, but I am confused. Where do I put the code to store the values? Can someone please post a generic code wherein I can understand where exactly I am going to be receiving my HR values and storing them?

Comment: are you asking from what device you are going to be receiving your HR values from???

Comment: No, I am asking. How do I implement the timer? Like, I am receiving the HR values as soon as the device sends them. And now I wish to store 60 seconds worth of the values and then send it to another function for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

there Are several ways to perform that.

1. **Using Handler()**

   ```
   //Start Code for Timer
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          //This will call after 60 second. Call your Function here 
       }
   },(1000*60));
   ```
2. **CountDownTimer**

   See [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) here

   ```
   new CountDownTimer((60*1000), 1000) {

       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           // this will call in every 1 sec
       }

       public void onFinish() {
           //This will call after 60 second. Call your Function here 
       }
   }.start();
   ```

Comment: Alright, thank you. So I don't need to create a timertask or anything? This code above is enough?